# What are the possible reasons that a NoClassDefFoundError would be thrown despite using a Maven Shade Plugin?

Tags: java, maven, maven-shade-plugin

**What are the possible reasons that a NoClassDefFoundError would be thrown despite using a Maven Shade Plugin?**

For example error thrown:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/xtext/xbase/lib/Exceptions
        at delight.fileupload.FileUpload.parse(FileUpload.java:23)
```

Here's the shade plugin config:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>shade</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <transformers>
            <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
              <mainClass>com.mybusiness.MyJarEntryObject</mainClass>
            </transformer>
          </transformers>
          <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: A possible reason could be a dependency that has a _scope_ of `provided`.

Comment: Some reasons: reflection or dependency's scope and/or optional flag.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I think you're right